# Decomposing Schur functor applied to a tensor product

Tags: rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, symmetric-functions, schur-functors

I want to compute
$$
S^{2,2,\dots,2,1}(\mathbb C^{2m-1} \otimes W)^{SL(2m-1)}
$$
Here $m$ numbers should appear in the superscipt of the Schur functor, and the last superscript means to take $SL(2m-1)$ invariants (of the action on $\mathbb C^{2m-1}$).

To take the invariants, one could decompose the Schur functor as a sum over terms like $S^\mu(\mathbb C^{2m-1}) \otimes S^\nu(W)$, and then just keep the terms with $\mu = (1,1,1, \dots, 1)$.

For a fixed $m$, I can compute this decomposition with a computer, and so I can guess the answer. It should be $S^{m,m-1}(W)$.

How can I prove this? The Cauchy identities would do the job if the Schur functor were instead $S^{2m-1}$ or $\bigwedge^{2m-1}$, but I need something more general.